# Is there a way to pass parameters when using vaadin Page.getCurrent().open() method?

Tags: java, vaadin

I am trying to open a window or popup and pass some values to it.
Id like to POST with Parameters.

I am currently using vaadin 7.7.6, com.vaadin.server.Page.getCurrent().open() which opens the url in a new browser window, don't know how to pass values and as well is it possible to make it a pop up instead of opening a new browser window

```
    private PNativeButton button()
    {
        if (button== null)
        {
            button= new button("Press Me");
            button.getNativeButton().setHeight(36, Unit.PIXELS);
            button.setEnabled(true);
            button.addClickListener(new ClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
                {
                    getCurrent().open("https://stackoverflow.com/", "Pressed", 100, 100, BorderStyle.DEFAULT);
                }
            });
        }
        return button;
    }
```

I'm expecting a new pop up window which POST the url with certain parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not state which Vaadin version you are using. But I am guessing it is Vaadin 8. If this is true and your objective is to open browser tab with external page, I would recommend to use [BrowserWindowOpener](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.2/com/vaadin/server/BrowserWindowOpener.html), since it has convenient API to add query parameters.

```
BrowserWindowOpener opener =
    new BrowserWindowOpener(url);
opener.setParameter("parameter","value");

Button button = new Button("Press me");
opener.extend(button);
```

The above will open a new browser window or tab, if you desire to open a popup the Window component (see the other answer for example) is more suitable approach.

In order to show foreign content in a Window component you need to use either [BrowserFrame](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.2/com/vaadin/ui/BrowserFrame.html) (which is using `iframe`) or [Embbeded](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.2/com/vaadin/ui/Embedded.html) component to wrap the url as component. You can find couple of examples in [Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-embedded.html).

Comment: Thanks, but it vaadin 7.7.6 let me update to include the version

Comment: Thanks for info, BrowserWindowOpener works also with Vaadin 7 series.

Comment: I edited the answer. Together with the other answer here you should have the options presented and finally it is up to your application what is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could extends Window class and add some additional parameters to it. For example:

```
class MySub extends Window {
    private String message;

    public MySub() {
        super("Sub Window");
        center();
    }

    public void initContent() {
       setContent(new Button(message, event -> close()));
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
   }
}
```

And use it to your UI

```
public static class SubWindowUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        MySub mySub = new MySub();
        mySub.setMessage("Close me !");
        mySub.initContent();

        addWindow(subWindow); // Open it in the UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have just updated the question to be more specific. I am looking at open a popup window that opens up a url that I post certain hidden parameters to.